# Помогите из строки вытащить число

Tags: c

Из этой строки нужно вытащить 12 и дальше работать  с ним.

```
"Принято в Socket->ReceiveBuf() 12 байт:"
```

Comment: Можно. Универсальный подход (но не факт, что самый эффективный):  пройдитесь циклом по строке-источнику и проверяйте каждый символ. Если цифра (только не изобретайте велосипедов, есть `isdigit()`) - добавляйте его в конец строки для результата.

Comment: Или - дойдите до первой цифры, после чего воспользуйтесь `sscanf()`, `atoi()` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то типа

```
#define  ERROR_VALUE   -1

char * s = "Принято в Socket->ReceiveBuf() 12 байт:";


int getFirstInt(char * s)
{
    char * c;
    for(c = s; *c != 0; ++c)
    {
        if (isdigit(*c)) return atoi(c);
    }
    return ERROR_VALUE;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("Get %d bytes\n",getFirstInt(s));
}
```

Правда, тут не отрабатываются *отрицательные* значения...

Comment: С отрицательными значениями легко поправить -- `return c > s && c[-1] == '-' ? -atoi(c) : atoi(c);`

Answer (score -1):

будет и так работать `return c[-1] == '-' ? -atoi(c) : atoi(c);` ведь на первой итерации и так c > s

Comment: Как раз на первой итерации `for (c = s; ...)` c равно s

Comment: Итерации еще нет - c равно s - это первый вход в  цикл. Затем ++с и с используется. Я не прав? Те значение с на 1 итерации будет sizeof(*с)  больше, чем s. Прошу прощения, код ваш конечно был. Но работает и так, как я написал выше - я проверил.

Comment: Вы о коде функции `getFirstInt()` в ответе @Harry? Инкремент (++c) выполняется в самом конце каждой  итерации. В  начале  первой `c == s`, поэтому если первый символ в `s` цифра, то в выражении `c[-1] == '-' ? ...` произойдет доступ к памяти, не входящей в `s`, что вообще говоря, не правильно (UB).

Comment: Да, конечно. Вы правы. Я поторопился. Просто мы же рассматриваем ту строку, которая есть, без универсального подхода. Да - на первой с=s. А с99 разрешает на следующий элемент за последним посмотреть (в массиве)? (Точнее, определить указатель) или на предшествующий первому?

Comment: тогда так `int getFirstInt(char * s)
{
    char * c;
    for(c = s+1; *c != 0; ++c)
    {
        if (isdigit(*c)) return c[-1] == '-' ? -atoi(c) : atoi(c);
    }
    return ERROR_VALUE;
}`

Comment: Тогда число (без знака) не может быть в начале строки. Не универсально. / А чего Вы, собственно, добиваетесь?

Comment: @avp просто интересно поиграть с кодом.

Comment: Хорошее дело. Главное побольше отладочной печати, проясняющей обстановку.